# how to scalarize multi objective functions

Tags: optimization

i have a multiobjective functions that i need to optimise it using GA. how to scalarize the functions to get a single function and do the optimization? the functions and constraints are in the attached picture
thenk you inadvance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCWj4.png)

Comment: What does GA stand for?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: GA is genetic algorithm